# Inspirations for Software UI

Tags: user-interface

Do you know any source for nice looking software designs? (non Web).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always [Apple Design Awards](http://developer.apple.com/ada/) or something like the Mobile User Experience Awards for mobile applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good examples on http://emberapp.com. Mostly for Mac though ...

Comment: The site itself, or things it lists? The site itself opens with a banner featuring unreadable (on my otherwise unchallenged monitor) medium-grey text on a dark-grey background; not *immediately* suggesting it's an icon of great design. :-) But with you and Abizern both recommending it, I think I must be missing something...

Comment: yea, the site itself looks ok but has also its advantages like T.J. Crowder said, - but there are nice looking inspirations in the "User Interface Design" section: http://emberapp.com/explore/categories/user-interface-design  
(thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at http://quince.infragistics.com/, while not complete applications, it does show you some best practices/design patterns for both Windows and Web applications.

I'd also take a look at some of the Windows Forms component companies, DevExpress, Telerik and Infragistics. You can learn a lot from the look and feel of their components.

Answer (score 0):

In this case... a lot of programmers tend to talk only about the worst examples...cause UI really depends on personel taste.

Have a look at this question for the worst examples:
[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/worst-ui-youve-ever-used)

From my point of view i prefer clear looks...nothing fancy etc...but it really depends on the software and topic...hope this helps